# Form displays without <form> after page renders

Tags: forms

everyone!

I'm trying to embed custom form (only file upload item, will attach the code below). But I see only inner stuff like divs and inputs. No form tag at all.

In page callback I use function that calls theme. here's hook_menu() and page callback

```
    $items['invite/%'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'invite_page_content',
      'page arguments' => array(1),
      'access callback' => 'invite_check_access',
      'access arguments' => array(1),
    );

    $output = array(
      '#theme' => 'invite_view',
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#content' => array(
        'g_id' => $g_id,
        'g_name' => $g_name,
        'user' => $user,
      ),
    );

    return $output;
```

In theme file I have call of the form

```
    $attachment_form = drupal_get_form('invite_attachment_form');
    echo render($attachment_form);
```

Here's form function

```
    function invite_attachment_form($form, &$form_state) {
      $form['attachment'] = array(
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#name' => 'upload_attachment',
        '#title' => t('Attach additional file?'),
        '#upload_location' => 'public://email-attachments/',
        '#upload_validators' => array(
          'file_validate_size' => array(2 * 1048576),
          'file_validate_extensions' => array(
            'png gif jpg jpeg mp4 ogg avi mov wmv flv ogv webm txt pdf zip rar',
          ),
        ),
      );

      return $form;
    }
```

Any help appreciated!

## UPDATE

I've found what was the reason for such behavior. There is some script in my site that deletes first form element. So if I add  before my form render - everything will be ok. Need to find what is it.

Comment: Have you tried it with a default theme from core to see if it still happens?

Comment: @acrosman, Thanks for the tip, will try and let you know

Comment: @acrosman Tried it with default theme and it works. Do you know what it could be?

Comment: By now you probably figured out the reason I asked: once you know it works in the default themes and not your own, you know your theme is the most likely cause and therefore the place to search.

Answer (score 0):

```
$attachment_form = drupal_get_form('invite_attachment_form');
echo drupal_render($attachment_form); //That should work
```

see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7.x

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it does not work :(